# Enable just small portion of NSWindow?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I must achievement somenthing tricky in my application for MAC OS, and because it's not easy to explain I will put an image:  [custom window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTgbD.png)

I created the `NSWindow` from image but the problema is how can create the `NSView` (the blue one) which is over and which have the purpose to block other action from user and just left small portion to be active. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Custom NSView and draw clear color for enbaled rect area  and disabled color for rest of the area. Capture the mouseDown event for the custom view and discard all the mouse events outside enabled rect area and if the mouse down in enabled area then call the mouse down event to the control behind the enabled area.

Comment: for me it's more easy to go with Ken Thomases aproach, thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be better to put up a sheet with a dialog to ask the user for the required information (and prevent interaction with the rest of the window) instead of mimicking a *very* un-Mac-like UI?

For example, consider the UI when creating a new project or adding a file to a project in Xcode.

If you really must attempt this, don't use a view to cover the window. Use another window. Make it borderless. Set its `backgroundColor` to `[NSColor clearColor]` and its `opaque` property to `NO`. Set its `hasShadow` property to `NO`. Set its frame to match the content rect of the window you want to block (or maybe its frame if you need to prevent interaction with its title bar).

Attach your overlay window to the main window as a child, using `-addChildWindow:ordered:`.

For the `contentView` of the overlay window, create a view that will draw the semi-transparent color everywhere except for over the control you want to leave accessible. To get that rect in the main window's coordinate system, you would use something like `[specialView convertRect:specialView.bounds toView:nil]`.

Comment: unfortunately I must respect layout. Your suggestion like OK and I will try in this mode.